# Angular passing variables between child and parent modules defined in a grandparent

Tags: html, angular, typescript, inheritance

lets say I have a grandparent class in angular that has an html that looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <child></child>
</parent>
```

The parent has a variable that the child needs to render and it is passed by the parent to the child which binds it into it's own predefined html. How can I accomplish this? ViewChild and ContentChild both seem to not be working entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say the parent and child components look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <div>
      My name is {{name}} <br>
      children: 
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent {
  name = 'Donald Duck';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      My parent is called {{parentName}}
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() parentName: string;
}
```

then you can reference parent using template variable:

```
<parent #parent>
  <child [parentName]="parent.name"></child>
</parent>
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-moa7n8

EDIT: Answering question from comment:

> This is pretty close, but is there a way where I can do that assignment within the parent or child and keep the grandparent as simple as possible?

Yes, you can achieve that using `ContentChild` and `AfterContentInit` lifecycle hook.

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;

  name = 'Donald Duck';

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.child.parentName = this.name;
  }
}
```

Then grandparent template would be as simple as:

```
<parent>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrtghy

Comment: This is pretty close, but is there a way where I can do that assignment within the parent or child and keep the grandparent as simple as possible?

Answer (score 0):

At first, use @ViewChild to referance to child component then use AfterViewInit; to pass variable - you need to wait for the view to be initialized before you can access your @ViewChild

Comment: can this be used in conjunction with @Wilhelm's answer to allow the parent or child to get these properties themselves